# How to host a worker role and web role in a single cloud service with just one instance?

Tags: azure, cloud, cloud-hosting

We have a project which has one web role(WCF Service) and one worker role. The worker role uses on an average 0.34% of the resources. We would like to host both the WCF and worker role in a single cloud service with a single instance. How can this be done? For now, the worker role and WCF service each use one instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with Sandrino's answer, but from the question, it doesn't look like any threading is required. My answer is to just move everything from `WorkerRole.cs` in the worker role into `WebRole.cs` in the web role.

Comment: Indeed - all you need to do is add an override to the Run method, see http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2011/12/how-to-combine-a-worker-role-with-a-mvc4-web-role-into-a-single-instance

Comment: Interesting, will try and let you know.

Comment: One doubt, will the run method be called everytime a WCF request is made?

Comment: `Run()` is called once, and is where you'd typically just sleep, inject monitoring/logging, etc. As soon as this method is exited, the instance begins its shutdown sequence. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127476.aspx) by Cory Fowler for more info on role instance lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ThreadedRoleEntryPoint](http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2012/02/combining-multiple-azure-worker-roles.html) for this:

```
public class WebRole : ThreadedRoleEntryPoint
{
    ...

    public override void Run()
    {
        List<WorkerEntryPoint> workers = new List<WorkerEntryPoint>();
        workers.Add(new MyWorkerRole());
        base.Run(workers.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Instead of inheriting from the default `RoleEntryPoint` you can use the `ThreadedRoleEntryPoint`, which allows you to pass a list of workers that it should start as a background thread. This way you can save resources by hosting one or more WorkerRoles as a thread in the WebRole.